# Markdown + Pandoc + Beamer: fails to insert tables

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, beamer

I am using `pandoc` on Linux to convert a Markdown file into a pdf beamer presentation.

I am trying to insert a table using the formats found [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html), but I get errors:

```
dario@dario:pandoc presentation.markdown -s -t beamer -o presentation.pdf

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@doifinframe ...e}[c]{@{}rllc@{}} \toprule 
                                              \addlinespace Right & Left...
l.254 \end{frame}
```

This is the markdown that produces the error:

```
| Right | Left | Default | Center |
|------:|:-----|---------|:------:|
|   12  |  12  |    12   |    12  |
|  123  |  123 |   123   |   123  |
|    1  |    1 |     1   |     1  |
```

I have also tried with multiline and grid tables with no luck.

I am not interested in a particular table style, just one that works easily.

Comment: What version of `pandoc` and `pdflatex` are you using? It works fine here with standard installation on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Hey daroczig: `pandoc 1.12.2.1 Compiled with texmath 0.6.5.2, highlighting-kate 0.5.5.1.` and `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) kpathsea version 6.1.1` So you suggest that it shouldn't be an issue with the markdown code...

Comment: I suspect that other parts of your `presentation.markdown` is causing the error.

Comment: I tried with just that code...

Comment: I am having this same issue and have verified the answer shown below does not fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer at [this Google groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/9HT2yBycTvo)

To fix this problem, you should either update your pandoc distribution (it's mentioned that version `1.12.3.3` is OK) or fix it's default beamer template file (for ubuntu it is `/usr/share/pandoc/data/templates/default.beamer`).

To fix the style file, you should replace the line

`\usepackage{longtable}`

with the line

`\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}`

Or, of course, you can use your custom template file to avoid fixing the system files

Comment: thx for finding that: even though it did not fix the problem for me it is helpful info